# Are Debug Routines MSVC++ specific?

Tags: c++, debugging

Are the Debug Routines found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1666sb98(v=VS.100).aspx
specific to MSVC++ or are they C++ Standard?

What do other compilers provide?

Comment: The answers so far indicate that they are specific to MSVC, but that's not strictly correct. They're specific to Microsoft's C Runtime Library (CRT), but you can link with that library using any compiler/linker. It's just that it's used by default with the Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: @CodyGray: They are specific to MSVC in that the debug libraries are not redistributable separately from Visual Studio so although you can link to them using some other compiler you can only get them bundled with Visual Studio. They're not part of a separately redistributable library or SDK that MS supply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not specified by the C++ standard. They are MSVC specific.
For GCC debug related options see **[this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

They are specific to the MSVC environment, they're not part of standard C++.

Other environments provide other tools, you need to ask about specific environments for specific answers. For example on linux, although not a direct replacement to debug routines, valgrind is a very useful too for debugging memory issues.